# Reason for rejection

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My in-law applied for UK visit visa with his wife and only son. He is self employed and employed part time with a Korean company. And also employed freelancer with another company in Nigeria. He submitted his business registration certificate, his bank statements for his business and his personal bank statement and his dollars account. All his account statement reflects all the payments he receives. He submitted his payslip. Can someone help explain each paragraph of the refusal. And the eco said he is traveling with his wife and children instead of child [image]

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e/92122#92122

Comment: Note that even if the applicant had all the necessary paperwork to justify the stated revenues, they only amount to less than 600 GBP per month, which is less than half of the minimum wage in the UK. This is already a huge red flag for an ECO or IO. Once you take away monthly costs (which are not discussed here), the available revenue must be a fraction of that, which means the cost of the trip probably represents a year of savings or so, which is another red flag, especially at this time where you have to spend a significant part of the trip in quarantine.

Comment: Also, spending 1800 pounds on a 21-day trip for 2 adults and a child without anyone funding your trip is just not credible. Between the flights, transport to and from the airport, accommodation, food, and any costs associated with a visit, this is just not conceivable in the UK (even for a single person). I’m afraid there is very little chance the application will be accepted unless the personal circumstances change very significantly (for real, not just whatever is written on the application). An application for tourism or family visit in Covid times is even less likely to succeed.

Comment: The 1800 pounds is for one adult and an infant. His wife is sponsoring herself. And for accommodation his wife uncle gave them an invite. Which he stated that he will be responsible for there accommodation and feeding through out there visit. What do you think we can do to correct the refusal.

Comment: You’re focused on funds whereas the ‘genuine visitor’ aspect looks more important. The ECO thinks they are a flight risk. What type of business is his employment? Do they have a prior travel history? Why do they want to visit now? Given they have family in the UK, what compelling reason can the family show to demonstrate to an ECO that they won’t overstay?